# Do not convert numerical column names to float in pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file where column name might be a number, i.e. `2839238`. I am reading it using `pd.read_excel(bytes(filedata), engine='openpyxl')` and, for some reason, this column name gets converted to a float `2839238.0`. How to disable this conversion?

This is an issue for me because I then operate on column names using string-only methods like `df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]`, and it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

Column names are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the type of the columns.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

the number you gave in the example shows that maybe you have a big numbers so python can't handle the big numbers as int but it can handle it like a float or double, check the ranges of the data types in python and compare it to your data and see which one you can use

Comment: I don't need int. I need pandas to **not** convert the column header value to numbers at all, why can't it do that?

Comment: pd.read_excel(bytes(filedata), engine='openpyxl', header=None)

Comment: i understand it in this way if it isn't the solution please can you give me more details

Comment: OP does not need this.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you don't have any duplicate column names.  Pandas will add .0 or .1 if there is another instance of 2839238 as a header name.

See description of [mangle_dupe_colsbool](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=panda%20read_excel#pandas.read_excel)

which says:
Duplicate columns will be specified as ‘X’, ‘X.1’, …’X.N’, rather than ‘X’…’X’. Passing in False will cause data to be overwritten if there are duplicate names in the columns.